# please how do i remove the other accounts from the phone

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

When I decide to download an app in the Google play
I will see some information written it reads authentication is required sign in to you
Google account.

Comment: can you post a screenshot? I don't quite understand where the problem is and a picture might help... Are you already signed in with a google account? Check your settings > accounts > google account

Comment: Are you talking about "Permission dialog"? It seems the app you want to download is utilizing Google account for some features to work. If it's, then you just need to accept that dialog. Else, cancel it and find another app.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see how many google accounts you actually have under Settings > Accounts > Google. if you have more than one. select the rest and remove them.
If you only have one google account under there, then remove it and add it again so that it re-authenticates.